how to find compliance bcc email programmatically(api or soql query) in salesforce
I have to find compliance bcc email for a salesforce org. I am unable to find underlying object for it. Also search of salesforce API to get bcc email but could't succeed.
Can anyone help how can I find compliance bcc email for an org programmatically (either by soql query or salesforce API).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can query the Organization object to get this information.
SELECT ComplianceBccEMail FROM Organization

This works in Apex:
Organization thisOrg = [SELECT ComplianceBccEMail FROM Organization];

REST API:
/services/data/v61.0/query?q=SELECT+CompliaceBccEmail+FROM+Organization

And any other API that supports querying the Organization object.
Note that the Organization object returns exactly one record for users that are not provisioned as a salesforce.com employee, so you do not need to apply a limit or any other filters.
